# Directory created in Chinese but I have English set in Windows 10

Tags: c#, directory, chinese-locale

I create a folder but the folder come up in Chinese and in the bin\debug folder, while I'm using Windows 10 in English and French. Some texts are also in Chinese but I don't want this, I need English Text in my program.

I checked all the languages package in my Windows but nothing about Chinese.

```
public static String actualDefaultFolder = @"C:\Data\";

private void myfunction() {
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo lookupDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(actualDefaultFolder);
    lookupDir.Create();
    lookupDir.SetAccessControl(new Sytem.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity());
}
```

Comment: That usually happens when you pass ASCII text to something that expects Unicode. I cannot see how it could happen with this code.

Comment: In fact when I write directly the name instead of actualdefaultFolder it works, but when I use my static string actualDefaultFolder it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have invisible characters in the string literal? Can you re-type (not copy) into a new variable?

Comment: That's it, in fact I read the datastring in a PLC and this function was wrong and added characters to the string. Thanks a lot! It was the line value =      _AdsClient.ReadAnyString(handle, 80, Encoding.Unicode); that inserted error.